# Deploy servicestack angular 2 app to elastic beanstalk

Tags: angular, servicestack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to deploy app to elastic beanstalk. I tried to use deploy from visual studio (aws plugin) but it seems like does not make webpack related stuff to build. gulp file from solution is meant to deploy to a single instance. What is best way to create package for elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `01-package-server` and `02-package-client` Single [Page App Gulp tasks](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-single-page-apps#gulp-tasks) it builds and bundles your entire ASP.NET Web App in the stand-alone `/wwwroot` folder, which you could xcopy to a remote server (configured with with an IIS App) to deploy your App.

Running the `www-msdeploy-pack` subtask will create an MS WebDeploy package of the `/wwwroot` folder in **/webdeploy.zip** which I'm hoping you can use to deploy your App to Elastic Beanstalk.

Otherwise you may need to run **msbuid.exe** on the command-line on the `/wwwroot` folder with the parameters Elastic beanstalk expects.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - which actually means that server reterned index html instead of js css ect. files itself exists

Comment: @Roman so something's not right, e.g. maybe the bundled files weren't packaged, not in the expected location, etc.